# Magento 2 How to fetch rest API array value

Tags: magento2, admin, array

I got sales order details from Rest API.

[image]

How to fetch this values(like When i call base_currency_code it will show USD).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an APi response is converted into array, You can fetch 'base_currency_code' by writing a loop as below.

```
$itemData = arrya();

foreach($apiItems as $item)
{
  $itemId = $item['item_id'];
  $itemData[itemId]['base_currency_code'] = $item['base_currency_code'];
}

print_r($itemData);
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying @amitkumar.
I got result myself.

Comment: kindly upvote me, if my answer is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

This is my result,

```
foreach ($result['items'] as $item){
print_r($item['base_currency_code']);
echo '<br>';
}
```

Finally i will get all order details.
Thanks you.